# Как дописать что-то в унаследованный метод, но чтобы старый функционал сохранился, C#?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Работаю с unity, мне нужно чтобы были разные типы врагов, но у них есть общий функционал (передвижение, например), поэтому я унаследовал от общего класса новый, и мне нужно в дочернем дописать что-то в метод Update так, чтобы сохранился старый функционал.

Comment: Вероятно, вам нужен Шаблонный метод - Template method. Это один из паттернов GoF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полиморфизм, ничего необычного

```
public class Enemy
{
    public virtual void Move()
    {
        Debug.Log("base move");
    }
}

public class Beast : Enemy
{
    public override void Move()
    {
        Debug.Log("override move");
        base.Move();
    }
}
```

Проверка

```
Enemy enemy = new Beast();
enemy.Move();
```

Вывод в отладку

```
override move
base move
```

То есть у родителя пометьте метод `Update()` как `virtual`, а у наследника как `override` и вызовите код родителя из наследника через `base.Update()` в начале или конце метода, в зависимости от ваших потребностей.

Comment: Нужно не забыть в потомке вручную вызвать базовый метод.